# javax.validation: Constraint to validate a string length in bytes

Tags: java, string, validation, byte, constraints

I'm using `javax.validation` to validate some bean fields' values.

This is what I use normally:

```
public class Market {

    @NotNull
    @Size(max=4)
    private String marketCode;

    @Digits(integer=4, fraction=0)
    private Integer stalls;

    // getters/setters
}
```

This will make sure that every `Market` instance has a market code with a maximum length of `4` characters and a number of stall with a maximum of 4 integer digits and 0 decimal digits.

Now, I use this bean to load/store data from/to DB.

In the DB I have table `Markets` defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MARKETS (
    MARKET_CODE VARCHAR2(4 BYTE) NOT NULL,
    STALLS NUMBER(4,0)
)
```

As you can see, I have `MARKET_CODE` which can be at most 4 *bytes* long. The `@Size` annotation will check if the string is at most 4 *characters* long, which is wrong.

So, the question is: is there an annotation like `@Size` that will check for the string bytes instead of the characters?

Comment: 4 bytes in what encoding? You'll probably need your own validator which effectively checks `"string".getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8).length`

Comment: Are the characters in the marketCode guaranteed to fit in one byte each?

Comment: @ptomli They seem to be `WE8MSWIN1252`. The problem is that I'm on a testing environment, I don't know if the DB on the production environment will have the same encoding...

Comment: @Simon No. If it was guaranteed, I wouldn't be searching for an annotations that checks bytes :)

Comment: @BackSlash then your problem is underspecified. A character is not a byte, and without knowing how your application is going to convert characters into bytes, known as encoding, then you simply cannot tell how many bytes any given string will occupy. Either your application specifies which encoding, as part of a custom annotation, or your application specification documents what will be used. You *need* to know the encoding to be able to specify the number of bytes, which you're trying to do in *static* code. This puzzle is missing some pieces

Comment: @ptomli I agree with you. I'll tell my boss that it's _required_ to know exactly which character set we are going to use. Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check the [Hibernate Validator documentation on Creating custom constraints](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#validator-customconstraints).

Your validator will need to encode the `String` into a `byte[]`, using some default or specified `Charset`. I imagine you might well use UTF-8.

Maybe something like this, which uses a hard coded UTF-8 encoding and assumes a suitable annotation, as outlined in the Hibernate documentation linked.

```
public class MaxByteLengthValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MaxByteLength, String> {
    private int max;
    public void initialize(MaxByteLength constraintAnnotation) {
        this.max = constraintAnnotation.value();
    }
    public boolean isValid(String object, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintContext) {
        return object == null || object.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8).length <= this.max;
    }
}
```